# Sum of complex series : $1+z+z^2 + \cdots + z^{n-1} = 1 + i \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Show that $$1+z+z^2 + \cdots + z^{n-1} = 1 + i \cot \left(\frac{\pi}{2n}\right)$$ where $z = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) + i \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

This question has confused me slightly and has left me rather stuck.

My attempt so far has been:

Note that $z = e^{i\frac{\pi}{n}}$ and that $$1+z+z^2+\cdots + z^{n-1} = \frac{1 - z^n}{1-z} \\ = \frac{1- e^{i\pi}}{1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{n}}} = \frac{2}{1-e^{i\frac{\pi}{n}}}$$

but I don't see a way to go from here...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You missed the $i$ in your expression of $z$.

Comment: @XiangxiangXu Thank you, this is updated, but that doesn't help me still...

Comment: Now you are very close to the answer. Hint: $\frac{2}{1 - e^{i\frac{\pi}{n}}} = \frac{2(1 - e^{-i\frac{\pi}{n}})}{(1 - e^{i\frac{\pi}{n}})(1 - e^{-i\frac{\pi}{n}})}$

Comment: You should reduce the dominator to real number, that is $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{ab^*}{bb^*}$.

Comment: @XiangxiangXu So I obtain $$\frac{2-2e^{\frac{-i\pi}{n}}}{2 - 2\cos(\frac{i\pi}{n})}$$ but this is a problem, as I am struggling to obtain the $\frac{\pi}{2n}$ for the argument...

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove Further expand the numerator and see what you need to prove :)

Comment: Also, the denominator should be $2 - 2 \cos(\frac{\pi}{n})$, please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1+z+z^2+\cdots + z^{n-1}$$

$$ = \frac{1 - z^n}{1-z} $$

$$ = \frac{1- e^{i\pi}}{1-z} $$

$$= \frac{2}{1-z }$$

$$=\frac{2(1-\bar z)}{(1-z)(1-\bar z) }$$

$$=\frac{2(1-cos(\pi/n)+i\sin(\pi/n))}{2-2\cos (\pi/n) }$$

$$=1+i\frac {\sin(\pi/n)}{1-\cos(\pi/n)}=1+i\cot(\pi/{2n})$$

In the last step  half angle identities were used.

Answer (score 1):

You have already found that
$$1 + z + x^2 + \dots + z^{n-1} = \frac{2}{1-e^{i \pi / n}}$$
Now note that 
$$\begin{align}
\frac{2}{1-e^{i \pi / n}} - 1 &= \frac{1 + e ^{i \pi /n}}{1 - e ^{i \pi /n}} \\
&= \frac{1 + e ^{i \pi /n}}{1 - e ^{i \pi /n}} \cdot \frac{e^{-i \pi /2n}} {e^{-i \pi /2n}} \\
&= \frac{e^{- i \pi / 2n} + e^{i \pi / 2n}} {e^{- i \pi / 2n} - e^{i \pi / 2n}} \\
&= \frac{2 \cos(\pi / 2n)}{-2i \sin(\pi / 2n)} \\
&= i \cot \left( \frac{\pi}{2n} \right)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

First notice $$1-e^{i\theta} = 2\sin(\theta/2)e^{-i\theta/2}.$$

Indeed, we know from trigonometry that
$$1-\cos(\theta)=2\sin^2(\theta/2) \quad\text{and}\quad \sin(\theta) = 2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)$$
and therefore
$$1-e^{i\theta} = (1-\cos(\theta)) - i\sin(\theta) = 2\sin(\theta/2)e^{-i\theta/2}.$$

With that in mind we have
$$\frac{2}{1-e^{i\theta}} = \frac{e^{i\theta/2}}{\sin(\theta/2)} = 1+ i\cot(\theta/2).$$

Taking $\theta = \pi/n$ we obtain the result you want.